# How design a button in Eclipse for Android App, so when you click, it takes you to a website

Tags: android, button, web

I already asked this question, but got answers that don't work and it counted as "Answered". Maybe someone knows how to design button in Eclipse for an Android app, so it takes you to a website ?Let's say this website.Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you say "...takes you to a website" do you mean it launches the Android web browser?  Or do you mean it loads the website in a `WebView` within your application?

Comment: It loads website I guess in webview. And it doesn't matter if my application will be active or not after this. For example  user has a choice of two button: go to google.com or stackoverflow.com. User decides to click stackoverflow button and it loads this website on user's screen.

Comment: I successfully finished lessons where a website loads in webview once user starts application. However, I don't know how first give e user choice of several websites before loading it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Say u wanna go to google.com

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onOpenWebBrowser(View v)
{
    Intent webPageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    webPageIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.co.in/"));

    try {
              startActivity(webPageIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

    }
}

}
```

Make sure u add uses internet permission to the manifest!

Answer (score 0):

you can refer the following to get an idea ,

see this vogella from there, you can get idea how to create android app which has a Button

http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html

and then create WebView in xml and map it in java, as

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

and For mor info refer android people.com

http://www.androidpeople.com/

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/index.html

and also read my blog to know about android basics

http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com/p/corridor-your-foremost-footstep-in.html

Comment: Thanks, Sankar. I actually spent much of my day yestarday in Barns and Nobels and Borders book stores trying to find answer to my question. I did see both of those lessons by Vogel and the other one, but I guess what I really need is a sample of the code for eclipse. I can not find it anywhere...

Comment: @Andy: If you feel this answer is useful then you upvote it and accept this answer

Comment: Problem is also, in Vogel lesson he gives you Fahrenheit to Cel. calculator. I am not that advanced to switch from Fahrenheit calculator to webview.

Comment: @Andy: you want to calculate what, am i not able to get your above comment,pls explain in detail

Comment: What I am saying is that Vogel gives example of calculator with a button, but what I really need is example of on-click button that opens  specific website.  I am not too advanced to take calculator lesson and use it for my purposes..Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: @Andy: no problem , pls refer the second link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set up an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) and tie it to your button. In the Listener's onClick method, you would load the specified URL into the WebView, which, based on your comments, it sounds like you've got that part figured out.